# What is the intersection of all $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ spaces?

Tags: lp-spaces

I wondered this, and tried to find an answer online, but the only thing I could find was a statement that the set of functions which are in all $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is well-studied. But what functions *are* in all $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ spaces?

If the answers are very different, I’d be interested in both the $p<\infty$ and the $p \leq \infty$ case.

Comment: Are [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463437/l-infty-and-the-intersection-of-the-spaces-lp) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268910/union-and-intersections-of-l-p-spaces-and-proper-subsets) of any interest to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an application of interpolation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) for a related theorem, or use Holder's inequality), this is just the set $L^1(\mathbb{R^n}) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$. So any bounded, integrable function is in every $L^p$ and vice-versa.

So the moral of the story is that the endpoints tell you everything.

Comment: Does this hold regardless of whether one considered $L^\infty$ in the intersection? Or only if it is included?

Comment: I see that I didn't really answer the second part of your question. I don't believe there's a particularly nice characterization if you don't have the actual endpoint. You may be interested in BMO, which plays a role in many endpoint estimates as a replacement of boundedness.